# Excel code to select a Column even if there are empty cells

Tags: vba, excel, select

Hi i am currently using this code but it only select the column until it find an empty cell, what i want is to select the column since the H3 cell until the last value in that column even if there are empty rows

```
Range("H3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

[image]

Comment: see this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1065-excel-select-empty-cells.html)

Comment: Your link give me an idea of first replace the blank values and then select all the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simple. First, declare a variable which can hold the last row used in the column you are interested and declare a variable to hold the range and set it. It will help you in the long run.

e.g. look at the following code...

```
Sub Test()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

'This will find the last row used in column H
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

'Set the Rng variable
Set Rng = Range("H3:H" & LastRow)

'Now do whatever you like to do with this range, like
Rng.Select
MsgBox Rng.Address
Rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
'etc

'If you want to perform multiple actions on the same range, you can also use With and End With block like below

With Rng
    .Value = "Test"
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .RowHeight = 25
    'etc
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @subodh_tiwari_sktneer Could you do something similar to find the last column, and then put the two together to find the last row and column dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

```
with activeworkbook.sheets("sheet1")    ' you did not mention sheet name
    range(.range("h3") , .Cells(.Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp)).select
end with
```

that said. try not to use `Select`. why are you selecting the range?